# How to animate the gif in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to use a animate gif in my UI,and here is my code:

```
#here self is a subclass of QFrame
self.on_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('Icon//on.gif')
self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
self.label.setPixmap(self.on_pixmap)
```

However,when I run the module,the gif is static.

If I want to animate the gif,how should I do?

Comment: http://unlogic.co.uk/2012/11/02/animated-gifs-in-pyqt/

Comment: @HaseebR7 It doesn't work,if I use QPixmap,I can see a static image,but if I use QMoive,I can see nothing.

Comment: @HaseebR7  OK,I forgot to use start().It works now,thanks